# Using this set in constructor in then

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to set `this.variable` in `then`? I know I can pass a regular variable, but can this be done with one set in the constructor as well?

```js
class Test {
    constructor() {
        this.variable = false;
    }

    aFunction() {
        someExternalThing(document.body, {
            option: 1
        }).then(function () {
            this.variable = true;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You can if the callback has the correct this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/3001761

Comment: Use an arrow function in this case to set `this.variable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, what you will need to change in your code is the declaration of the .then () parameter function

You must use arrow function for `this` to keep the class reference

Ex:

```
.then(() => { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `this` keyword is referring to the function.
Try this:

```
aFunction() {
  const that = this;
  someExternalThing(document.body, {
     option: 1
  }).then(function () {
     that.variable = true;
  });
}
```